# Browser independent String(DD-MON-YY) to Date conversion

Tags: javascript, firefox, date-format

An external service returns date in String in DD-MON-YY format(eg. "30-JUN-12") which needs to be converted to date type to pre-populate in date-picker. I am using new Date() javascript function which works fine in Chrome but gives invalid date in Firefox, Edge and IE.

Comment: What does the Javascript code, which you use look like?

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: check moment.js: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @Geshode - I have simply used new Date(str), where str = "30-JUN-12"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Added "19" for years greater than 50 and "20" for years less than 50

**Chrome, Edge (Chromium) and Firefox**

```js
const convert = str => {
  let [dd, mmm, yy] = str.split("-");
  yy = (+yy > 50 ? "19" : "20") + yy;
  return new Date(`${dd} ${mmm} ${yy} 15:00:00`);
};
console.log(convert("30-JUN-12"));
console.log(convert("29-FEB-80"));
```

**This for IE11**

```js
var convert = function(str) {
  var parts = str.split("-");
  parts[2] = (+parts[2] > 50 ? "19" : "20") + parts[2];
  return new Date(parts[0] + " " + parts[1] + " " + parts[2] + " 15:00:00");
};

console.log(convert("30-JUN-12"));
console.log(convert("29-FEB-80"));
```

Comment: We cannot assume it to be 20xx every time. It can be "30-JUN-97". Chrome itself consider 97 as 1997 and 12 as 2012. But Firefox gives invalid for 2-digit-year(YY)

Comment: Then you need to set a year to decide what is in 19xx and what is in 20xx

Comment: Confirmed with third-party service provider and added "19" for years greater than 50 and "20" for years less than 50

Comment: @Philomathy I made a function for you

Comment: Thanks for this function. This would help.